# Is there any tool for displaying ActionScript class hierarchy?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

Is there any tool to generate a class hierarchy graph (like UML) for ActionScript3 projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Crocus Modeler ( http://crocusmodeller.com/ ).  It is still not free ($49), but does support round trip coding.  I use it to generate documentation from existing code, or generates stubs from a diagram.  It is specific to MXML/AS3, so all of the features are directed to coding in flex.

Answer (score 3):

I have no experience with this application, but a little google-fu found **[UML4AS](http://www.uml4as.com/flower-platform/home-uml4as.html)** which claims that it generates class diagrams like you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the link, +1'd. Unfortunately it costs more than what I would like to spend on a UML tool, so a free (or significantly cheaper) alternative would be much preferred

Comment: @KayZhu I believe I read that there is a trial period, so you can at least get a few days out of it :)

Comment: Awesome, I will try it out :)